# Zeepelin not using Spark scheduler pool

Tags: apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise, apache-zeppelin, datastax-startup

I have Zepplein 0.158 installed.

`spark.scheduler.pool=test` in the Interpreter UI and also in zeppelin-env.sh. 
`zeppelin.spark.concurrentSQL=false` in the Interpreter UI and also in zeppelin-env.sh, if this is true, spark-sql jobs get assigned to fair pool.

I want my jobs to run against the test pool I have created in Spark.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, concurrentSQL has to be set to true for spark.scheduler.pool to be set to fair.

https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/interpreter/spark.html